# Importing a file using only part of the file name in Python

Tags: python, csv, file, import

I am trying to import a file , where the part of the changes daily and randomly. Current date is the part of the file name, but this is already taken care of. The last part of the file name has numbers that change at random. How do I make sure that the last part is ignored?
Here's the current line:

```py
data = pd.read_csv(yesterday.strftime('I:\Example\import\Example_NEW_%Y-%m-%d-VARIABLE NUMBERS HERE.csv'))
```

The file for today is called:

```
Example_NEW_2022-06-20-00-00-48
```

Tomorrow this could be:

```
Example_NEW_2022-06-21-00-00-13
```

Comment: Try `.strftime(r'...`

Comment: Use os.listdir to find existing files and filter to the one you want.

Comment: The `glob` module allows wild-carding for the filenames, and returns a list of full paths to the matched files.

Answer (score 1):

If you are confident that there is only one file with one date,

```py
import glob
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

date_str = datetime(YEAR, WEEK, DAY).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
file_path = glob.glob(fr'I:\Example\import\Example_NEW_{date_str}-*.csv')[0]
data = pd.read_csv(file_path)
```

Comment: @AaronLei The date I am using is yesterday's date (or 2 days before if it's a Monday), does that also work with the code you provided? 
The code for date is as follows:
def DateFind():
    yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)
    if yesterday.weekday() > 5:
        yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=3)
    else:
        yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)
    return(yesterday)

Comment: @NiMingDe I don't quite understand what do you mean _(or 2 days before if it's a Monday)_ . You can do `today = datetime.now()`, `date_str = (today - timedelta(days = (2 if today.isoweekday() == 1 else 1))).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`.